# Alter create content form when logged in as admin

Tags: nodes, forms, modal-dialogs, users

Can I alter the form where you add content (logged in as administrator, so in the overlay)? I know how I can alter the form when logged in as a user like this:

```
function xmed_form_product_node_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {

}
```

But how can I do this for administrator in the overlay?

UPDATE:

when I do hook_form_alter in my template.php of my subtheme and dump the form variable nothing happens when I open form in overlay... Also tried this in a custom module. NOTHING shows.

Comment: Same form  is displayed for both of them .. It's just overlay vs simple page.. It should get changed in both the places.. Did you try ?

Comment: I think I know, because the admin theme is different so I need to create a subtheme from my admin theme and put it there, correct?

Comment: That's one way - or just use `user_access()` in a module to determine what to show for what type of user

Comment: What's the most easy way and best practice way to do this?

Comment: Depends - if you're writing a theme, do it in the theme. If you're writing a module, do it in the module

Comment: And how should I do this in a module? I have created a custom module, and now I want to adjust my create content form in admin overlay ..

Comment: You've already got what you need - hook_form_alter and user_access. I'm not gonna write it for you!

Comment: I'm seeing nothing in overlay when I try to alter the form. See updated topic ..